# How to use link_to to pass value back to a search field and execute in RAILS, RoR?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, variables, methods, link-to

I have a search field and button. When the user searches something like "cat" my view renders a bunch of related keywords such as "catnip", "cat toys", "cats" etc... each of these results are links, and are to pass the value of the string displayed back into the search to generate results for the selected link. For example:

1. User renders search page and searches for "cat"
2. view page renders results related to "cat" such as "catnip" "kittens"
3. User now clicks on "catnip"
4. View page renders results related to "catnip" such as "grass"

Is this possible with link_to? I'm lost and not quite sure what to do...

--

My Code:

```
SEARCH VIEW PAGE

<% form for(:search, url => search_path) do |f| %>
Search: <%= f.text_field :search %><br>
<%= f.submit "Search Keyword" %><p>   

<% unless @keywords.nil? %>
  <h3>Keyword Results</h3>
  <% @keywords.each do |k| %>
  <%= link_to k.name, :controller => "search", :action => "keywords", value => k.name %>
<% end %>

SEARCH CONTROLLER

def keywords
  if request.post? then
  @keywords = googlesearchapi(params[:search])
end
```

I want to pass the link_to value that the user clicks on as the :search parameter... thanks in advance for any advice~~

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you want the link to be: "../search/keywords?search=catnip", to do this, modify the link_to as:

```
<%= link_to k.name, :controller => "search", :action => "keywords", :search => k.name %>
```

Then, you need to delete the line `if request.post? then`, otherwise it won't handle the requests coming from link_to, as it is a GET request (not POST).